# SubClass ParseObject Cannot resolve method

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

I am trying to SubClass a ParseObject, which seems to work ok except the method can't be resolved. Android Studio seems to be able to find the class - at least the IDE links back to the original class PhotoSession, it just can't find the method and I get a cannot resolve method error.

```
import com.parse.ParseClassName;
import com.parse.ParseObject;


@ParseClassName("PhotoSession")
public class PhotoSession extends ParseObject {

    public PhotoSession() {

    }

    public void setDisplayName(String value) {

        put("displayName", value);

    }
}
```

Creating a PhotoSession object from another class:

```
private void createNewSession() {

    ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    ParseObject photoSession = new PhotoSession();
    photoSession.setDisplayName("test session");

}
```

I've registered the class in the Application class before Parse.initialize(...) like so:

```
 ParseObject.registerSubclass(PhotoSession.class);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closely here:

```
private void createNewSession() {
    ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    ParseObject photoSession = new PhotoSession();
    photoSession.setDisplayName("test session");
}
```

The problem is this line:

```
ParseObject photoSession = new PhotoSession();
```

You are creating a new PhotoSession object but with type ParseObject. Create it with type PhotoSession instead:

```
PhotoSession photoSession = new PhotoSession();
```

Since PhotoSession is a subclass of ParseObject, it is valid to declare a new PhotoSession as a type ParseObject. You don't want that though, because that is casting it to it's parent class, which removes any specific methods that exist in a PhotoSession object. This is called upcasting, and in this case you do not want to do that